# MIPS Printing Values of a Given Array

Tags: mips

I am trying to print on the console the values of the array, which are already given as intA in .data. I.e., trying to print values of an array without user's prompt.

My code:

```
.data 

prompt: .asciiz "The values in the array are:\n"
finished: .asciiz "\nNo more values to present"
space: .asciiz " "
intA:   .word   11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 34, 0

.text 
.globl main

main:

    #Prints the prompt string
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, prompt 
    syscall 

    # initialization of a0, a1, and t3 (i, counter)
    la $a0, intA # loading starting address (base) of array in register a0
    addi $a1, $zero, 6 # array size - 1
    addi $t3, $zero, 0 # i initialized to 0

    j loop

loop: 

    lw $t1, 0($a0) # loading integer (value of array) in the current address to register t1, I use lw because integer is a word (4 bytes)

    # printing current value of array
    li $v0, 4
    la $a2, ($t1) 
    syscall 

    # spacing between values
    li $v0, 4
    la $a2, space
    syscall 

    # checking that next address is not outside of the array
    addi $t3, $t3, 1
    slti $t2, $t3, 6
    bne $t2, 1, done   

    # accessing next integer and jumping back to print it
    addi $a0, $a0, 4
    j loop

done:

    # indicating program is done
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, finished 
    syscall
```

The output that I am getting: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Q2TI.png)

Any idea why it doesn't print the values of the array, and also what are these squares that are printed instead?

**Edit:**

I changed

```
# printing current value of array
    li $v0, 4
    la $a2, ($t1) 
    syscall
```

to

```
# printing current value of array
    li $v0, 1
    lw $a2, ($t1) 
    syscall
```

Because, from what I understand, I print an integer so $v0 should be fed 1, and I should lw and not la (because it is an integer, i.e, a word)

However, now I get a runtime error in line 31: `lw $a2, ($t1)` Telling me that

> fetch address not aligned on word boundary 0x0000000b

Comment: `lw $a2, ($t1)` <-- `$t1` contains the current element, so why are you trying to use that as an address? Also, register `$a2` has nothing to do with system call 1.

Comment: Because I am trying to print the value of `$t1`, why is `lw $a2, ($t1)` means using it as an address? Also, I've used `$a2` to print the value, do I have to use `$a0` for that?

Comment: Like I said, you already have the value in `$t1` after doing `lw $t1, 0($a0)`. And yes, system call 1 expects the value to print in `$a0`. The only SPIM syscalls that use `$a2` for anything are 13, 14, and 15.

Comment: I changed `lw $a2, ($t1)` to `lw $a0, ($t1)`. What I want, is to print the current value of the array, this is why I am including that line. I am new to assembly, and based on what I know (probably wrong, as it is not working), to print the value, I need to: `li $v0, 1` to tell the system I want to print a value, then `lw $a0, ($t1)` to feed `$a0` the value to be printed, and then `syscall` to prompt the printing. Where am I wrong?

Comment: Solved it, thank you buddy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Instead of `lw $a0, ($t1)` for printing the value of `$t1`, I need to do `add $a0, $t1, $zero`, because I am trying to use the value and not to access an address.